# Comparing array of object value in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to comparing array of object value in dart?

```
main() {
  var datas = [{'name':'Andrew', 'age':31},{'name':'Dorian', 'age':27}];
  for( var data in datas){
    if(data['age'] > 27 ){
      print(data['age']);
    }
  }
}
```

because with that code i got this error

```
The operator '>' isn't defined for the class 'Object'.
Try defining the operator '>'.dart(undefined_operator)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that you can not perform the comparison because the compiler doesn't know the type of `data['age']`, you can extract the value and assign it to an int variable using `as` to cast it like this:

```
var datas = [
  {'name': 'Andrew', 'age': 31},
  {'name': 'Dorian', 'age': 27}
];
for (var data in datas) {
  int age = data['age'] as int;
  if (age > 27) {
    print(age);
  }
}
```

Or you can declare the array specifying its type instead of using `var`:

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> datas = [
  {'name': 'Andrew', 'age': 31},
  {'name': 'Dorian', 'age': 27}
];
for (Map<String, dynamic> data in datas) {
  if (data['age'] > 27) {
    print(data['age']);
  }
}
```